# How to avoid 2 equal loopings | Django

Tags: python, django, database, loops

I got this code:

```
    i = 1
    for item in cart:
        data_ps[f"itemId{i}"] = item
        data_ps[f"itemDescription{i}"] = item.category.name
        data_ps[f"itemAmount{i}"] = item.sell_price
        data_ps[f"itemQuantity{i}"] = '1'
        i += 1

    total_value = format(((shipping_price + cart_price) / installment), '.2f')
    data_ps['installmentValue'] = total_value

    response = requests.post('https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions', headers=headers,
                             params=params, data=data_ps)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        for item in cart:
            Sell.objects.create(item=item,
                                date=timezone.now(),
                                discount=Decimal(0.00),
                                total_paid=cart.get_total_price(),
                                buyer=request.user, )
```

As you can see, there are 2 `for item in cart` loop. After the first one, I need to get a request.post and then check if the status_code is equal 200. If so, the code gerenates another `for item in cart` loop.

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the second looping adding all this information inside the first one, because it just update a record in my database ('Sell.objects.create').

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: If the work done in the second loop can't happen until after the POST, and the POST can't happen until after the first loop, what do you think you can change?

Comment: I would say these loops are semantically divorced, and there is not reason for you to feel like it's necessary or desirable to merge them.

Comment: If you expect the `response.status_code == 200` to be `True` most of the time, you could create the items in the database in the first loop and then delete them again if the status_code is not 200. Depending on how long it takes to create/delete data from the database, you have to weigh this against how often you expect the status code check to fail.

Comment: @ScottHunter, maybe I could migrate all the code inside the second loop to the first one BUT not record the data inside de PostgreSQL. And then, if the status_code == 200, I'd just force to do the task in the db, without a loop. I think we can do something like this with forms with the "save" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a value to your `Sell` model `cart`. You can do something like this:

```py
total_value = format(((shipping_price + cart_price) / installment), '.2f')
data_ps['installmentValue'] = total_value

i = 1
for item in cart:
    data_ps[f"itemId{i}"] = item
    data_ps[f"itemDescription{i}"] = item.category.name
    data_ps[f"itemAmount{i}"] = item.sell_price
    data_ps[f"itemQuantity{i}"] = '1'
    Sell.objects.create(
        item=item,
        date=timezone.now(),
        discount=Decimal(0.00),
        total_paid=cart.get_total_price(),
        buyer=request.user,
        cart=cart,  # <= ---------- New ----------
    )
    i += 1


url = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, data=data_ps)

if response.status_code != 200:
    Sell.objects.filter(cart=cart).delete()
```

With this approach, technically, you are not removing the `for` loop from the logic; You're just moving it inside the database query. So it's a tradeoff. Is the response `status_code` equals to `200` most of the time? Or it fails most of the time? You should make a decision in this tradeoff.